# ¿Cómo puedo consultar un Id en especifico en firebase usando xamarin forms?

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarinforms

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en xamarin forms, con la cual pueda interactuar con una aplicación de escritorio en C#, la idea es poder enviar datos desde la aplicación de escritorio y leerlos en xamarin y viceversa, no comparte se relación.
La estructura que le tengo a la tabla es diferente la creada xamarin por defecto.
Necesito poder consultar un dato en especifico según el tipo y sede de la empresa.

Les dejo la imagen de la estructura, aquí deseo consultar y que me muestre el código 1 que es el id del producto, a ver si alguien me echa una mano con la consulta por favor, y así guiarme para todas las demás tablas.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]